# How to enable the notification using the vscode extension API?

Tags: notifications, vscode-extensions

I developed a vscode extension with a file modification feature. It includes a confirmation message for the user to confirm whether the target file should be operated.

However, a user reported an issue with not being able to use it due to the disabled notification setting.

I would like to know if there is a method to access the notification activation setting and turn it on if it is currently false.

[image]

I researched the VSCode documentation and GitHub, and it appears that the configuration should not be modified using a VSCode extension. Is there a way to manage the notification? If not, I will need to find another method to meet the requirement.

Comment: You could `showErrorMessage` which is a little shady but does get around the setting disabling notifications as error messages are still shown.  That is probably preferable to messing with the user's settings.   And yes, you can modify any setting in an extension.